# Count the number of times a data is repeated in the table sql Query

Tags: sql

I have a database that has many tables, and one that only has relationships, from that table I need to obtain the number of times a data is repeated in the table

I want to make a query that returns the id of the person who has exactly 2 homes

```
SELECT
    person.name AS 'name',
    person.id AS 'id of person',
    home.location AS 'location of home'
FROM
    person JOIN intermediary
    ON
    person.id = intermediary.person
WHERE
    COUNT (
        SELECT
            person.id_person
        FROM
            intermediary JOIN person
            ON
            intermediary.person = person.id
    ) = 2
```

This is what I thought, that in the where it is counted how many times each person appears and if it appears 2 times that it returns only that.

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQX0c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic idea is the following:

```
SELECT (A BUNCH OF FIELDS)
FROM (GIVE ME THE JOINED TABLES (PERSON + INTERMEDIARY + HOME))
WHERE
    Person.id = (
        (GIVE ME THE ID OF THE PERSON WHOS ID IS APPEARING EXACTLY 2x INSIDE INTERMEDIARY)
    )
```

Joining the tables is easy enough with two consecutive JOINs:

```
(Person JOIN Intermediary ON Person.id = person) JOIN Home ON Intermediary.home = Home.id
```

For the id of the person who is appearing twice in the intermediary table, we just count how often each person appears in the table by using the `GROUP BY` operator:

```
SELECT person, COUNT(person) as 'count' FROM Intermediary GROUP BY person
```

...from which we select only the rows where `count` = 2, by wrapping the just mentioned query (Q) like so:

```
SELECT person FROM ( Q ) AS personHomeCount WHERE personHomeCount.count = 2 LIMIT 1
```

It is assumed that a combination of a person and a home is unique and can only appear once in the table. Additionally, note the `LIMIT 1` as we can only accept one value returned by the query. If multiple people have exactly two homes, the first person will be the selected one.

Finally, stiching these queries together, we get:

```
SELECT
    Person.name,
    Person.id as 'id of person',
    Home.location as 'location of home'
FROM
    (
        (
            Person
            JOIN Intermediary ON Person.id = person
        )
        JOIN Home ON Intermediary.home = Home.id
    )
WHERE
    Person.id = (
        SELECT
            person
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    person,
                    COUNT(person) as 'count'
                FROM
                    Intermediary
                GROUP BY
                    person
            ) AS personHomeCount
        WHERE
            personHomeCount.count = 2 LIMIT 1
    )
```

Here is the SQL-Fiddle for further demonstration: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nJrmwtQfASzTPp851Q9SSf/0

Hope I could help!

Comment: Wonderful explanation, it helped me a lot, thanks, and I have another question as you mention only the first person who complies with this will be shown, it would open some way to change the LIMIT so that it shows me all or I can access with a query the first time, then modifying the same query to access the second one and so on?

Comment: @Caquita1414 Yes, you can omit the `LIMIT 1` and do a classical query as well. You would then need to replace the `WHERE` clause with another `JOIN` to get the desired table. One approach would be the following: `... (THE JOINED TABLES) JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT person, COUNT(person) as 'count' FROM Intermediary GROUP BY person) AS personHomeCount WHERE personHomeCount.count = 2) AS doubleHomePerson ON doubleHomePerson.person = Person.id`. I've updated the fiddle once more to illustrate the query.